# nodejs android studio and passport js login 404 error

Tags: java, android, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an issue when trying to login to my node js local server via my android application.
Each time I try to log in I receive 404 error. I can register users fine using the Post route and can see it in my mongodb database with the username and password(hashed+salted).

But when I log in with my credentials(username and password) correctly I always get 404 error. Which I think means my login route is not correct.

To login my mobile app posts to the login route and sends the username and password.
But on running my success and fail routes do not post their corresponding console logs and I get 404 error. I have checked the username and password and they are correct.

```java
app.post("/signup", function(req, res)
{
    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email}), req.body.password, function(error, user)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(400).send();
        }
        else
        {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){//Use the local strategy to login the user
                res.status(200).send();
            });
        }
    });
});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {//Middleware
    successRedirect: "loginsuccess",
    failureRedirect: "/loginfail"
}), function(req, res){
});


app.get("/loginsuccess",isLoggedIn, function(req, res)
{
    res.status(200).send();
    console.log("Login worked");
});

app.get("/loginfail", function(req, res)
{
    console.log("Login failed");
    res.status(400).send();
});
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
}
```

Comment: To add to this the component witin app.post and the function after does not run and just returns 404 so loginsuccess and fail are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue,

Need to alter the login route to not use successRedirect  and failure but instead use a return function.

```java
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {//Middleware
    //console.log("trying login");
    //successRedirect: "/",
    //failureRedirect: "/fail"
}), function(req, res){
    console.log("correct login");
    res.status(200).json(req.user);

});
```